# what different between Android plugin for Gradle and com.android.application?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

android studio use gradle to compiler android apk
gradle is a build system
so google write the plugin 'com.android.application'?
if this is ture why should a  dependencies {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'}
and what it use for?

the 2.1.3 seems to mean the version of android studio

what is the different between
the **com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3**  in

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
}
```

}

and the **com.android.application** in

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
}

dependencies {
}
```

Comment: no is different

Comment: How so? You need the `dependency` in the `classpath` in order to `apply` the `plugin`.

Comment: And I could be wrong, but the Gradle plugin version number isn't necessarily the same as the Android Studio version. For example, you are welcome to download the beta 2.2 versions of the Gradle plugin and use them on Android Studio 2.1.3

Comment: i see now i understand.so it switch the 'com.android.application' by classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3' thanks

Comment: No switch. The `classpath` allows you the ability to add the `plugin`.

Comment: You can't use the plugin without declaring it in the buildscript block. Take a look at documentatio: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android-gradle/2161/configure-your-build-with-gradle/7075/why-are-there-two-build-gradle-files-in-an-android-studio-project#t=201609090629426861609

Comment: gradle will find the plugin in classpath?